# SQL instance IP address pointing to the SQL server hostname

Tags: sql, ssms, multiple-instances

Our SQL instances IP addresses are pointing to the same DNS entry (which is the SQL server name) although the TCP/IP is enabled. My question is, how do you set up the SQL instances IP address and instance name properly so we can access it faster in SSMS using names?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) is a Windows-based, integrated environment. SSMS provides a single comprehensive utility that combines a broad group of graphical tools with a number of rich script editors to provide access to SQL Server for developers and database administrators of all skill levels.

In GCP, to set up the SQL instances IP address and instance name to access it faster in SSMS, you can use  Cloud SQL Auth proxy which is the recommended method for connecting to a Cloud SQL instance. Refer [1](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/connect-overview) on pre-requisite and set up guide.

To connect to your instance using SQL Server Management Studio, refer [2](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/quickstart) which shows how you can use other database tools.